# Saving response result to a file on new line without removing previous entry in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need help, saving response result to a file on new line without removing previous entry in JMeter. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save response data into a separate file there are 2 options:

1. Use [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) which is capable of storing the response data in .jtl files in XML format
2. Use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) which is capable of storing the response data in whatever format you need